# How to clip a .osm.pbf file to a shapefile in R

Tags: shapefile, openstreetmap, r

I have (1) an  OpenStreetMap file of a large area in `.osm.pbf` format that I would like to clip with (2) a shapefile `.shp` of a smaller area using R.

The output output I would like to get is a `.osm.pbf` file of the intersection between (1) and (2). Any ideas on how to do this in R ?

Reproducible example:

- [Here is the `.osm.pbf` file of the larger area](http://download.geofabrik.de/south-america/brazil-140101.osm.pbf)
- [Here is the shapefile file of the larger area](http://portalgeo.pcrj.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/32d59e46aca14e8196f4ebe0da73c5be_0.zip)

Comment: I have no clue about doing something in R myself, but you can browse the OSM wiki about [Frameworks](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Frameworks) and [OSM Scientific Tools](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_Scientific_Tools) ... and do a search there for "osmar". It seems that there is some tool for processing OSM data, but I was not able to figure out whether you can do some clipping.

Comment: crosspost: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36104643/how-to-clip-a-osm-pbf-file-to-a-shapefile-in-r

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure about how best to do this with R, but if you don't mind using the osmconvert tool (http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmconvert - binaries available for Linux/Windows/Mac), there are some options.

Clip using a rectangle:

```
osmconvert input-data.osm.pbf -b=10.5,49,11.5,50 -o=my-output-file.pbf
```

(south-west and north-eastern corners, lng/lat)

Clip using a polygon:

```
osmconvert input-data.osm.pbf -B=clip-polygon.poly -o=my-output-file.pbf
```

The '.poly' file is in the Osmosis polygon filter file format (http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis/Polygon_Filter_File_Format), that page shows you how to create one manually or there are some suggested tools for converting from other formats.

Comment: You can't do that with R, at least not without compiling protobuffers for R, as "*.pbf" is a serialized OpenStreetMap standard. In other words, you can export internal OSM format to PBF (smaller), or to XML (larger, but more compatible). 

As "tom" suggested above, use osmconvert. It's a reliable and fast tool (written in C)